# Count ways to take K alternative numbers from N numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Given N numbers from 1 to N , I need to choose K numbers (K=$0,1,2$.....$\lceil n/2 \rceil$) in such a way that if we choose number $i$ then we cannot choose numbers $i-1$ and $i+1$.

In case of boundaries , if we choose $1$ then we cannot choose $2$ and if we choose $N$ we cannot choose $N-1$.

Example : Let N=$7$ then here answer is $34$

Here are all $34$ ways :

{}

{$1$},{$2$},{$3$},{$4$},{$5$},{$6$},{$7$}

{$1,3$},{$1,4$},{$1,5$},{$1,6$},{$1,7$},{$2,4$},{$2,5$},{$2,6$},{$2,7$},{$3,5$},{$3,6$},{$3,7$},{$4,6$},{$4,7$},{$5,7$}

{$1,3,5$},{$1,3,6$},{$1,3,7$},{$1,4,6$},{$1,4,7$},{$1,5,7$},{$2,4,6$},{$2,4,7$},{$2,5,7$},{$3,5,7$}

{$1,3,5,7$}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**.  Either you will choose $N$ or not.

- If you do not choose $N$ then you have to choose numbers from $0$ up to $N-1$.
- If you do choose $N$ then you cannot choose $N-1$, so you have to also choose numbers from $0$ to $N-2$.

Use these ideas to formulate a recurrence for the required number $a(N)$, then solve the recurrence.

Comment: Cant their be some general forumla ? Also can you write down recurrence .

Comment: Please try thinking about it for a bit more than 30 seconds.  This is not a "do my homework for me" site.

Comment: Recurrence is fine.But I was thinking to generalise it for given N.And i Know its not "do my homework site"

Comment: I had tried it  for N=1 to 10.But  cant come up with any formula .

Comment: I made a computer program to execute this recurrence and test it for several values of N.

Comment: Try Googling "solve homogeneous recurrence example".

Comment: Is this your recurrence f(N,K)=f(N-1,K) + f(N-2,K-1)?

Comment: Almost right.  But there should not be any $K$ in it because as you have shown in your $N=7$ example, $K$ is not a fixed number, it could be $0,1,\ldots\,$.

Comment: Yeah By K I mean K ranges from 0 to ceil of N/2

Comment: I feel its coming out to be sum of N fibonacci numbers + 1 if am  wrong please correct me.Fibonacci numbers are : 1 1 2 3 5 8..

Comment: That's correct but you can simplify.  (Note that $34$ is a Fibonacci number.)  [Check this out](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Fibonacci_Numbers).

Comment: Hey...Its N+2 Fibonacci number..:).Am i right ?

Comment: I think am missing something..Am still getting wrong results

Comment: I think Fibonacci number $N+2$ is correct.

Comment: Yeah it is..Thanx..:)